# Has Many through with simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-many-through

I'm struggling to get going with a simpleform field for a hasmany through association.  When i submit the form the has_many records are not saved, and if the form doesn't validate the options are not selected when the form redisplays.  so in short, nothing is working.

I'm not sure how much automagic should be going on here, or if I am just missing code i need to make it work. I don't think it's a strong parameters issue as I am not getting a permit params error in the logs.

model

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :provider
    has_many :reductions
    has_many :activities, through: :reductions,  :autosave => true
...
```

view

```
<%= f.association :activities, collection: current_user.provider.activities.collect %>
```

controller

```
def update
  @coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id])
  if @coupon.update_attributes(coupon_params)
    redirect_to helm_coupons_path, notice: 'Coupon was successfully updated.'
  else
    render  "edit"
  end     
end
....
def coupon_params
  params.require(:coupon).permit(:provider_id, :code, :max_uses, :max_uses_per_customer, :name, :expires_at, 
    :dollar_discount, :percent_discount, :starts_at, :activity_ids => {})
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE:  log of create action as requested in comments:

```
Started POST "/helm/coupons" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 09:58:25 +1000

Processing by Helm::CouponsController#create as HTML

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h8OjO3zqPVofhgQ8VYECea4kCCnXU+Lkn7L2QPJUDcM=", "coupon"=>{"name"=>"test", "code"=>"test", "dollar_discount"=>"5", "percent_discount"=>"", "max_uses"=>"1000000", "max_uses_per_customer"=>"1000000", "starts_at(1i)"=>"2014", "starts_at(2i)"=>"8", "starts_at(3i)"=>"24", "starts_at(4i)"=>"09", "starts_at(5i)"=>"00", "expires_at(1i)"=>"2017", "expires_at(2i)"=>"8", "expires_at(3i)"=>"24", "expires_at(4i)"=>"09", "expires_at(5i)"=>"00", "activity_ids"=>["", "2", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Saving..."}

  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Provider Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "providers".* FROM "providers"  WHERE "providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Provider Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "providers".* FROM "providers"  WHERE "providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Coupon Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "coupons"  WHERE "coupons"."code" = 'test' LIMIT 1
  SQL (34.0ms)  INSERT INTO "coupons" ("code", "dollar_discount", "expires_at", "max_uses", "max_uses_per_customer", "name", "percent_discount", "provider_id", "starts_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["code", "test"], ["dollar_discount", 5.0], ["expires_at", "2017-08-23 23:00:00.000000"], ["max_uses", 1000000], ["max_uses_per_customer", 1000000], ["name", "test"], ["percent_discount", ""], ["provider_id", 1], ["starts_at", "2014-08-23 23:00:00.000000"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Coupon Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "coupons"  WHERE ("coupons"."code" = 'test' AND "coupons"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/helm/coupons
Completed 302 Found in 117ms (ActiveRecord: 39.1ms)
cache: [POST /helm/coupons] invalidate, pass
```

Comment: One thing i would say.For `update` action,you should add the `:id` the `permitted params`.`params.require(:coupon).permit(:id,:provider_id, :code, :max_uses, :max_uses_per_customer, :name, :expires_at, :dollar_discount, :percent_discount, :starts_at, :activity_ids => {})`

Comment: thanks @Pavan - the other parameters saved without that but good catch.  I've added that in.  - the activities still don't save though

Comment: Can you post the `server log`?

Comment: Turns out I just made a silly mistake. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459996/collection-select-for-has-many-through/25467584#25467584