# Collection select for has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get a collection select to show the submitted values as selected when the form redisplays? for example if a different field does not validate, the multi select box should show the selected items

```
<%= collection_select(:coupon, :activity_ids,
                            current_user.provider.activities, :id, :name,
                            {},
                            {:multiple => true, :class => 'chosens-select',   :name=>'coupon[activity_ids][]'}) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do.

```
<%= collection_select(:coupon, :activity_ids,current_user.provider.activities, 
:id, :name, {:selected => @coupon.activity_ids}, {:multiple => true, :class => 'chosens-select', :name=>'coupon[activity_ids][]'}) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to user [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). You will just do :

```
simple_form_for(my_model) do |f|
  f.association :activities
  f.button :submit
end
```

It will simplify all your forms.

Comment: Thanks Dougui  - I actually do use simpleform, however I couldn't get this working with that either, so i went back to basics with this approach.  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459673/has-many-through-with-simpleform?noredirect=1#comment39729748_25459673

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guys posting answers, It pushed me to give up "fixing" the form and look again at my controller.  Turns out I had made a mistake in the params statement:

```
def coupon_params
  params.require(:coupon).permit(:id, :provider_id, :code, :max_uses, :max_uses_per_customer, :name, :expires_at,
    :dollar_discount, :percent_discount, :starts_at, :activity_ids => {})
end
```

where it should be

```
def coupon_params
      params.require(:coupon).permit(:id, :provider_id, :code, :max_uses, :max_uses_per_customer, :name, :expires_at,
        :dollar_discount, :percent_discount, :starts_at, :activity_ids => [])
end
```

spot the difference? the activity_ids should be an array, not a hash

```
:activity_ids => []
```